# Is the "Boom" project vaporware or really going to happen?

Tags: airliner, supersonic

Is this https://boomsupersonic.com viable or more vaporware?

Any solid information?

Comment: It's "not my site" but it is incredibly naive to mark this as "opinion based".  A wealth of factual information on contracts and finances could be presented here.

Comment: It might help to add more to your question explaining the details you're looking for.

Comment: *"Is it really going to happen?"* cannot be answered here, unless one of the project managers drops by. If you were to ask if it is feasible given x, y, z conditions, then we can have a go at it. Your wording is a bit too much in the middle.

Comment: I'm afraid that just doesn't make sense, @AEhere .  Say someone in the air finance industry on here stated "As a matter of fact, they have N orders from X airline who have already paid M million euros on D date".  Surely, you would agree that is extremely firm and factual information towards the subject???

Comment: @Fattie it's evidence that an airline was willing to throw money at the project, no more or less. I'll echo what others have said so far about this question being opinion-based in its current format since there's no way to confidently say that anything will come of it.

Answer (score 1):

Technologically, it's possible -- though I question the "go twice as far" since supersonic aircraft typically consume much more fuel than their subsonic counterparts.

Economically, I doubt it'll be a success: unless you have technology that somehow limits or muffles the sonic shock wave footprint on the ground, and can prove it to regulators, your aircraft will be banned from supersonic flight over populated areas.  Operating and maintenance costs will push ticket prices, er, into the stratosphere, just as they did with Concorde -- and with the relatively small fuselage diameter that goes with supercruise, passengers who aren't dwarves will think twice about offering repeat business.

There may be a market for a supersonic bizjet -- and the BOOM illustration suggests this might be their target market (I don't see a lot of windows).  They'll still be limited top subsonic flight over land, however, which narrows the market to those who need to cross an ocean (that's not too wide) very quickly.

Comment: You know, i just naturally assumed they were using the anti-boom technology which has been around for ages now. (Eg, this demo is actually being welded up at the moment, I believe  https://www.newscientist.com/article/2165683-nasa-is-trying-to-build-a-supersonic-aircraft-without-the-boom/ )

Comment: While this answer is admirable related opinion, thanks, the question is asking for actual industry knowledge of the company / project .. hopefully someone has that

Comment: @Fattie The NASA boom-suppression test vehicle is, as far as I'm aware, the first attempt to actually flight test the technology.  What appears to work in CFD software or in a supersonic wind tunnel may not do what it needs to do in the air.  And jumping the gun on NASA seems like a pretty high risk level...

Comment: Zeiss - ah that is the first attempt.  Fascinating, thanks for that

Comment: And I might add that BOOM doesn't appear to incorporate any of the NASA tester's special feature (like the extremely slender nose -- requiring the pilot fly via camera and monitor screen -- and shockwave trapping canards).  BOOM looks like a scaled down Concorde, which is 1960s (or, charitably, 1970s) tech.

Comment: The second section about the Concorde is incorrect and a common misconception it was quite profitable and did not lose money, it was actually one of BA's best earning aircraft. [One of the former pilots covers everything in this podcast (worth a listen)](https://omegataupodcast.net/166-flying-the-concorde/). If anything it was _becoming_ expensive at the end of its life time as small batch parts suppliers closed up shops and the plane suffered from the higher wear of supersonic flight.

Comment: @Dave And yet the routes were never expanded -- for instance, a Mumbai to Sydney or Mumbai to Kuala Lumpur would have been within Concorde's range, and over water (almost entirely, with a little route management) -- and has money attached -- but no Concorde on that route.  If it was profitable, it should have gone more places than just the one route.  Tokyo to Anchorage to San Francisco is another route where it could have "beat" conventional airliners -- but it never flew anywhere but the Atlantic crossing.

Comment: @ZeissIkon you should listen to the podcast... A solid chunk of the Concorde's flying was actually charter operations to lots of places. [It also flew other schedule routes aside from the NY London trip](https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=324083)

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon a reason for atlantic crossings only routing (excluding charters mentioned by Dave) might very well be that it was the most profitable option. And then there's the fact that when something broke down, "homebase" was very close: imagine a technical at Sydney, with spares at good ol' Europe... the more expensive the plane, the more it must fly to keep it economical.

Comment: I thought the whole point of these smaller supersonic biz jets was that they were smaller and lighter than Concorde, which would reduce their boom to the point where they would be allowed to fly over land?

Comment: @RobinBennett I don't know that that's been demonstrated.  Are any of them flying yet?

Comment: No, none of them have flown or demonstrated a reduced boom, let alone actually receiving permission to fly supersonic over land - but I think they are reasonably confident of all three, or they wouldn't be investing in the project.

Comment: @RobinBennett Flying, no problem (modern software is pretty good).  Reduced boom, fairly likely, due to smaller size/weight as you note.  Permission to overfly populated areas above Mach 1?  Unlikely in today's environment without near-zero footprint demonstrated.